# Mixed SSL Content Preventing Joomla Installation/Operation with Nginx

Tags: ssl, nginx, joomla, reverse-proxy, mixed-content

I must be missing something obvious but I cannot install Joomla 3.6.5 on a site with SSL already in place due to mixed content.

I get the following in my browser console:

> Mixed Content: The page at 'https://example.com/joomla/installation/index.php' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://example.com/joomla/installation/index.php'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
>
> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://example.com/joomla/installation/index.php. Failed to start loading.

Web searches for "Joomla Installation on SSL" and similar all generate pages that assume a search for how to introduce SSL **`AFTER`** installation.

Appreciate ideas on how to avoid having to switch off SSL just to install Joomla.

## EDIT

Turns out this is an issue related to SSL Termination using a reverse proxy such as Nginx and that this does not affect Apache given the way Joomla v3.6 is written to operate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Joomla v3.7: Installation & Operation

Firstly, a test of Joomla v3.7.x beta from GitHub as of 30 Dec 2016, appears to indicate that this is not an issue with that version. The version can be installed and operated without further intervention.

This was tested with **`proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;`**, discussed below, already in place but without the need to set **`live_site`** variable in configuration.php.

---

## Joomla v3.6: Installation

If you try to install on a site already secured with SSL and a strict transport policy etc, the installation will fail due to mixed content. This failure is triggered when you press "Next" after filling in the items for Step 1 of 3 for the installation.

Note that this is a silent failure and you will simply find that there is no response after pressing the "Next" button. The only way to know there has been an error, is to check your js console.

To get around this, you will have to do some hacking:

- Around Line 357 in `/Installation/template/js/installation.js`,
  change `baseUrl = _base;` to `baseUrl =
  _base.replace("http://","https://");`
- Save and then start the installation.

Remember to clear your browser cache if you had already loaded the installation page before taking this action.

The installation folder is deleted after installation so this one-off hack is trivial.

---

## Joomla v3.6: Operation

Key thing is to remember **NOT** to set the force_ssl parameter in configuration.php or Global Configuration in the Joomla Admin. The default value of '0' doesn't mean use NONSSL as the wording may suggest, but to maintain the protocol used for the current request. See notes in `/libraries/joomla/application/route.php`.

### A) If using Nginx and FastCGI, such as PHP-FPM:

- In Joomla, set the **`live_site`** variable in configuration.php to
  **`https://example.com/path/to/joomla`**
- In Nginx, set `fastcgi_param HTTPS "on";` in the location block
  handing php

### B) If using Nginx and proxying PHP to Apache:

(In order of most to least desirable approach)

#### 1. If [mod_rpaf](https://github.com/gnif/mod_rpaf) is enabled in Apache:

- In configuration.php in Joomla, set the **`live_site`** variable to
  **`https://example.com/path/to/joomla`**
- In the location block handing php in Nginx,

  - Set **`proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;`**
  - Set **`proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;`**
  - Set **`proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-HTTPS "on";`**

  *Note that there are two versions of mod_rpaf around. The older, original version with a "0.6" version tag is most likely to be found after a web search.*

  *While it works perfectly well for forwarding the Real IP from a reverse proxy, it does not do the other things needed here. The newer, independently developed one, forwards the Real IP, Real Port, and, Real Protocol.*

  *Unfortunately, if installing using a package manager, you will almost certainly get the older version. So download from GitHub and install manually*

#### 2. If [mod_setenvif](http://www.helicontech.com/ape/doc/mod_setenvif.htm) is enabled in Apache:

- In configuration.php in Joomla, set the **`live_site`** variable to
  **`https://example.com/path/to/joomla`**
- In the location block handing php in Nginx, set **`proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;`**
- In Apache, set **`SetEnvIfNoCase X-Forwarded-Proto https HTTPS=on`**
  in the relevant htaccess or conf file

#### 3. If neither mod_rpaf nor mod_setenvif is available in Apache:

- In Joomla

  - In configuration.php, set the **`live_site`** variable to
    **`https://example.com/path/to/joomla`**
  - Around Line 73 in
    **`/libraries/joomla/document/renderer/html/head.php`**, change **`$base = $document->getBase();`** to **`$base = str_replace("http://", "https://", $document->getBase());`**
- In the location block handing php in Nginx, set **`proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;`**

  *This involves editing core Joomla files but as the next expected update is v3.7 where this issue appears resolved with the Nginx proxy_set_header directive in place, an upgrade should not result in any issues*

---

## References/Sources

1. https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/1021/reverse-ssl-proxy-support
2. https://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?t=845318#p3313092
3. https://www.hiawatha-webserver.org/forum/topic/1906

Answer (score 2):

I found in "libraries/joomla/uri/uri.php", around line 65 this code:

```
// Determine if the request was over SSL (HTTPS).
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && !empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && (strtolower($_SERVER['HTTPS']) != 'off'))
{
    $https = 's://';
}
else
{
    $https = '://';
}
```

It looks like that here the application is detecting it's SSL connection and obviously, fails when the server is behind a proxy that handles the SSL connection. For a test, I changed the else to 's://' and restored all other (previous) hacks. The " Mixed Content" issues are solved.
However, one extension (OS Membership Pro) is having a strange issue now.

The Joomla Core Developer should look into this, providing a overwrite to force SSL. The "force_ssl" setting in configuration.php is not working as expected.

Comment: Brilliant! If using fastCGI with Nginx, then instead of amending `/libraries/joomla/document/renderer/html/head.php`, just set  `fastcgi_param HTTPS 'on'`. This would avoid editing any core files. If proxying PHP to another webserver though, that hack would be needed as there is no `proxy_param` directive. The change to the live_site in configuration.php is needed in either case but this is not a hack.

Comment: Hi Dayo - good point. I check the fastcgi_param HTTPS  and provide a reply.

Comment: I just tested the soon to be released v3.7 and note that the issue appears to have sorted. So, with SSL Termination in a reverse proxy enabled, and all requests being sent to SSL, v3.7 works out of the box without any intervention required. Both for installation and operation. Also doesn't matter whether "force_ssl" is switched on or not (should be left at "0" in such cases though). In order words, v3.7 works as one would expect.